# Many to Many using Composite Key:how to add elements to the Table Between Entities?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

So I've been following this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

I want different VendingMachines to have different kind of Stock for different kinds of Brands.
So far following the tutorial and opening the H2 console looks like the Table Structure is correct.
And yet, I cannot manage how to add content to the Table which combines both Entities. I mean, Vending Machines are added,Brands are added, but cant manage to add stock.

I have

```
@Entity
public class VendingMachine {
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long vendingMachineid;
    String model;
    int maxBrandsAvailable;
    int maxStockperBrand;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="vendingMachine")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<BrandStock> brandstock;
```

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

    @Id @GeneratedValue long brandId;
    String name;
    double price;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand")
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<BrandStock> brandStock;
```

I also have Jpa Repositories for Both Entities.

The stock of every different Vending Machine related to a different Brand

```
@Entity
public
class BrandStock {

    @EmbeddedId
    BrandStockKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("brand_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    Brand brand;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("vendingMachine_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendingMachine_id")
    VendingMachine vendingMachine;

    private int stock;
```

And of course the Primary Key Generator for that Table

```
@Embeddable
class BrandStockKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "brand_id")
    Long brandId;

    @Column(name = "vendingMachine_id")
    Long vendingMachineId;
```

The method I am using to add elements looks something like this`, on a CommandLineRunner:

```
    BrandStock cocaColaForModel01 = new BrandStock();
    Set<BrandStock> stockForModel01 = new HashSet<BrandStock>();
    VendingMachine model01=new VendingMachine("Model01", 5, 10,null);
    stockForModel01.add(cocaColaForModel01);
    cocaColaForModel01.setStock(10);
    cocaColaForModel01.setVendingMachine(model01); 
    Brand cocaCola = new Brand("CocaCola", 1.75, stockForModel01);

    model01.setBrandstock(stockForModel01);
    cocaCola.setBrandStock(stockForModel01);

    brandRepository.save(cocaCola);    
    vendingMachineRepository.save(model01);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I did it. I was missing the repository for the different BrandStock as well as being careful with the order everything is created.

Comment: sure! how may I help you. This post here is sort of useless but I did manage to learn how to handle this kinf of relations :)

Comment: not too fond on putting my email around! Feel free to ask any question in here :-) I'll do my best!